Constructor on type 'xxxModel' not found
I am trying to convert from TableEntity to T however it throw the error says "Constructor on type 'xxxModel' not found." (xxxModel) is one of my models. So My code will be looks like:
        public async Task<Result<GetDataCommand<T>>> GetAllAsync(GetDataModelQuery<T> query)
        {
            try
            {
                var tableClient = _storageTableFactory.GetTable(query.TableName);

                var data = new GetDataCommand<T>
                {
                    Data = new List<T>()
                };

                var entities = tableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(query.Filter);

                await foreach ( var entity in entities)
                {
                    var model = ConvertToModel(entity);
                    data.Data.Add(model);
                }

                return   Result<GetDataCommand<T>>.Success(data);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _logger.Error(exception, "Error when getting data.");
                return Result<GetDataCommand<T>>.Failure("Error when getting data.");
            }
           
        }

        private T ConvertToModel (TableEntity entity)
        {
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), entity);
        }

There are bunch of different models got their own type will using "GetAllAsync" and all models are inherits from ITableEntity. And I am also checked all the models got constructor with default value. But still It give me Constructor on type not found. Any ideas why?

You can integrate below code into durable functions to get the table entity:
[Function("Get_Table")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> Get_Table(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData ri,
    FunctionContext execxt)
{
    string ri_tble_name = "test";
    ILogger ri_lg = execxt.GetLogger("Get_Table");
    string ri_cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
    var ri_tc = new TableClient(ri_cs, ri_tble_name);
    var rith = ri_tc.Query<TableEntity>(filter: "");
    var tab = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    foreach (var r in rith)
    {
        var d = RithConv(r);
        tab.Add(d);
    }
    ri_lg.LogInformation($"Hello Rithwik fetched the table, {ri_tble_name}.");
    var ri_out = ri.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    await ri_out.WriteAsJsonAsync(tab);
    return ri_out;
}

private static Dictionary<string, object> RithConv(TableEntity rith)
{
    var ri_dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var key in rith.Keys)
    {
        ri_dic[key] = rith[key];
    }
    return ri_dic;
}

Output:


